# Find and split on certain characters that follow words

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use regular expressions to split text on punctuation, only when the punctuation follows a word and proceeds a space or the end of the string.

I've tried `([a-zA-Z])([,;.-])(\s|$)`

But when I want to split in Python, it includes the last character of the word.

I want to split it like this:

```
text = 'Mr.Smith is a professor at Harvard, and is a great guy.'
splits = ['Mr.Smith', 'is', 'a', 'professor', 'at', 'Harvard', ',', 'and', 'a', 'great', 'guy', '.']
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You actually want to also split on whitespace. Try `re.findall(r'\w+(?:\.\w+)*|[^\w\s]', s)`

Comment: With NLTK, Spacy, etc. you will still have to use regex to override some cases like this. You should check [Spacy](https://spacy.io/usage/spacy-101), too, if you want to go NLP way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to do tokenize. Try `nltk`

http://text-processing.com/demo/tokenize/

```
from nltk.tokenize import TreebankWordTokenizer
splits = TreebankWordTokenizer().tokenize(text)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
re.findall(r'\w+(?:\.\w+)*|[^\w\s]', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lDDbx7/1).

**Details**

- `\w+(?:\.\w+)*` - 1+ word chars followed with 0 or more occurrences of a dot followed with 1+ word chars
- `|` - or
- `[^\w\s]` - any char other than a word and whitespace char.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/UVLaIt):

```
import re
rx = r"\w+(?:\.\w+)*|[^\w\s]"
s = "Mr.Smith is a professor at Harvard, and is a great guy."
print(re.findall(rx, s))
```

Output: `['Mr.Smith', 'is', 'a', 'professor', 'at', 'Harvard', ',', 'and', 'is', 'a', 'great', 'guy', '.']`.

This approach can be further precised. E.g. tokenizing only letter words, numbers and underscores as punctuation:

```
re.findall(r'[+-]?\d*\.?\d+|[^\W\d_]+(?:\.[^\W\d_]+)*|[^\w\s]|_', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lDDbx7/3)

Answer (score 1):

You can first split on `([.,](?=\s)|\s)` and then filter out empty or blanks strings:

```
In [16]: filter(lambda s: not re.match(r'\s*$', s) , re.split(r'([.,](?=\s)|\s)',  'Mr.Smith is a professor at Har
    ...: vard, and is a great guy.'))
Out[16]: 
['Mr.Smith',
 'is',
 'a',
 'professor',
 'at',
 'Harvard',
 ',',
 'and',
 'is',
 'a',
 'great',
 'guy.']
```